# Passing data from multiple sets of fields to a page for review and confirmation

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am very new to jquery so any help will be appreciated. I am using jquery 1.8.3 and ui 1.9.2. I have included jquery ui tabs inside a page, and within one of the tabs, I have multiple rows of fields that users can fill out and submit to a database.

PHP code (new_member.php):

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
<table id = "member">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Gender</th>
            <th>Birthday</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Surename</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><select name = "gender"><option value = "male">Male</option><option value = "female">Female</option></select></td>
            <td><input class = "date" name = "bdate" type = "text"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "name"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "surename"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select name = "gender"><option value = "male">Male</option><option value = "female">Female</option></select></td>
            <td><input class = "date" name = "bdate" type = "text"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "name"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "surename"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><select name = "gender"><option value = "male">Male</option><option value = "female">Female</option></select></td>
            <td><input class = "date" name = "bdate" type = "text"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "name"></td>
            <td><input class = "field_text" type = "text" name = "surename"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<input id="save" type="button" name="save" value = "Save"><br>
</form>
```

I am then using jquery to check for empty spaces and warning. Providing that all checks are ok, how can I pass the data to a php page where the user is asked to review before saving to a database? Any direction will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Just set the action for your form to the page you want to go to to display the confirmation, then build that page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<form action = "" method = "POST">
```

to

```
 <form action = "actionpage.php" method = "POST">
```

In actionpage.php get values using POST:-

```
$gender= $_POST['gender'];
$name= $_POST['name'];
and so on...............
```

Now echo this information to display it to user and include 2 button "confirm" and "cancel". If user clicks confirm store it in the database else redirect it back to the form page.

Comment: Thank you very much Vivek. Since there are 3 sets of data, how does $gender = $_POST['gender']; know which gender to get? Or will all genders be grouped into one Array?